# Will the inexistence param query filter raise Exception?

Tags: python, django

I have a Server model, when I query it, I use bellow filter condition:

```
qs = qs.filter(switchesport__switches__is_listing=True)
```

but there I have a question, the Server items may do not have the `switchesport.switches`, I mean the `server.switchesport=None`.

Could I use the query filter? will it get an Exception?

Comment: It won't raise an exception, but it will return empty QuerySet, as we expected.

Comment: thank you, but is there any source code can explain it?

Comment: I've added an answer with the reference to the doc. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [**Django official doc of `Lookups that span relationships`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> If you are filtering across multiple relationships and one of the intermediate models doesn’t have a value that meets the filter condition, Django will treat it as if there is an empty (all values are **`NULL`**), but valid, object there. ***All this means is that no error will be raised***